# Build an homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

I have a function $f:A \to B$, $B$ a topological space. How I build a topology on A such that $f$ becomes an homeomorphism? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is $f$ a bijection?

Comment: If $f$ is not a bijection, you don’t.

Comment: Yes, sorry! $f$ is a bijection

Comment: My question, or if you could give me an idea that how I can build that topology... In certain way it could be obvious but I don't know how to do that..

Comment: Don’t clarify in comments, clarify in the question. Edit your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the function $f:A\to B$ is a homeomorphism if it is bijective, continues and its inverse is a continuous function.

By this, there should be stated that $f$ has to be a bijection. Moreover, $X\subseteq A$ is open in $A$ if and only if $f(X)\subseteq B$ is open in $B$.

The later condition is a result of continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$. We prove this:

Let $Y\subseteq B$ be open in $B$, then there exists $X\subseteq A$ such that $f(X)=Y$, and since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(Y)=f^{-1}(f(X))=X$ must be open in $A$. Conversely, let $X\subseteq A$ be open in $A$, then there exists $Y\subseteq B$ such that $f^{-1}(Y)=X$, and since $f^{-1}$ is continuous, $(f^{-1})^{-1}(X)=f(X)=f(f^{-1}(Y))=Y$ must be open in $B$.

Comment: Well, thank you I can define the topology in $A$ such that $f$ will be an open map, right?

Comment: Openness of the map is not enough. It should be continuous too.
For an open set $Y$ in $B$, $f^{-1}(Y)$ has to be open in $A$ and there are no other open sets in $A$ except these.

Comment: What I am saying is: Let $f:A\to B$ is a bijective mapping and let $\tau_B$ be the topology on $B$. If we want to have $f$ as a homeomorphism, then $\tau_A =\{ f^{-1}(Y)\vert Y\in \tau_B \}$ must be the topology on $A$.

Comment: Yes, you right sorry, I have been thinking for a while!!! thank you

Comment: In fact, this is the core of topology. Two spaces are topologicaly equivalent if they have 'similar' structures of open sets. This 'similarity' is represented by a bijective mapping.

Comment: Yes, that's the way, thank you so much